# Word order Q : between two sentences, which one sounds more accurate? (Or is none of them right?)

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

*So I can use 7 words among those below and each one of them only once without chaning its form as it is presented here.*

[ frequency / take / regular / make / its /reflect / availability / will / place / amount / than / often / fluently / exactly / recognize / accessible / retrieval/ +more ]

"Metaphorically speaking, human memory is like a public library that organizes its book according to their predicted popularity. Frequently checked out books, that is, popular books, will be made available in special spaces near the entrance of library to make it easy for members to find them. In contrast, less popular books, the ones rarely checked out in the past, will be placed in the back of the library. Because the environment is thus reflected in our memory, we can use our memory to make inferences about the environment. 
*We can infer, for example, that the more often one encounters a piece of information, the _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ *."

Here are the two answers I came up with  : ........

1. more its accessible availability will take place.
2. more its frequency will make retrieval accessible.

Comment: Your problem poses several questions. The original quote reads **the more often we must have encountered it in the past.** But these individual words are not available from your list. Neither is **more** one of the words given. Neither of your suggestions is idiomatic. Who set this test? Where does it come from. (https://books.google.pt/books?id=P-54i3MY7rgC&pg=PA195&dq=Metaphorically+speaking+human+memory&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb-73d5rPmAhW1olwKHbKBAp0QuwUILDAA#v=onepage&q=Metaphorically%20speaking%20human%20memory&f=false)

Comment: Oh, thank you for pointing out the absence of 'more'~! I missed it apparently;; And I didn't try to find out the original quote but there it is. Thank you for the link, too. I encountered this question from another site and wonder what the answer would be.. Aside from the original quote, what could be a possible answer for this question by using those words in [ - ] ???

Comment: I now the word **more** included in the list. I cannot construct any sensible answer from the word list supplied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is the following:

> We can infer, for example, that the more often one encounters a piece of information, the **more often will availability reflect its frequency**.

It's not an entirely natural sentence, but I can see nothing that's entirely natural. (This seems the most likely of the lot.)

Without the exact 7-word limitation, the sentence could be rephrased to make it more natural:

> The more often will [its] availability reflect its frequency [of study].

(Note the addition of the second use of a pronoun and the addition of explanatory words at the end.)

In short, not only does the popularity of books warrant them being placed closest to the entrance, but (in reverse), placing books closer to the entrance makes them more accessible and, therefore, taken and studied (read) more frequently—resulting in them being more popular. So, placement and popularity end up influencing each other.